# empty character constant - too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-

Tags: c

I'm writing my code in C (Eclipse IDE) a got this error

The code is

```
{
printf("\nYour hat size is %c%c%c%%c\n",size[0][i],size[1][i],(size[1][i] == '') ? '':'/', size[2][i]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo `%%c` should be `%c`?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your array indexes are within the allocated bounds, first note that:

`%c%c%c%%c` has only three place holders. The first three `%c` will be replaced by the respective three arguments of `printf` and next is `%%c` which will print a percentage sign `%` for the `%%` present in the string and then simply print `c`. Although this will throw a warning.

Also you have `''` which is empty character constant and thus will throw an error. If you mean blank space then do `' '`; if you mean end of string null character then do `'\0'`.

Comment: Right. There is no such thing as an empty character.

Comment: printf("\nYour hat size is %c%c%c%c\n", size[0][i], size[1][i], (size[1][i] == '') ? ' ':'/', size[2][i]);

Comment: @Domi: in the last comment you still have empty character. What exactly you want to compare with the contents of `size[1][i]` ?