# Empty character constant in C

Tags: c

I've tried changing it to double quotes, but this is wrong. I also tried figuring out what it means, but the compiler keeps giving me the same error.

> [Error] empty character constant

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c - '0'];
        else if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c == '\n')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits = ");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("%d", ndigit[i]);

    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d \n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: (potential) Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755025/empty-character-constant-too-many-arguments-for-format-wformat-extra or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193454/empty-character-constant-in-c. Questions are different, but the answer is still the same as the answer for this

Comment: The error message is pretty obvious: Change  `''` to `' '`.

Comment: `"[Error] empty character constant"` -- this is one of those cases where the error really does mean exactly what it says..... `:)`

Comment: regarding: `main()`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` (regardless of what Visual Studio might allow)  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice they both have a return type of `int`

Comment: regarding: `else if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c == '\n')`  This should be: `else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') // space, newline, tab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty character constant error is because of the following comparison in the `else if` clause.

```
c == '' //  '' is empty
```

Replace `''` with `' '`.

Comment: thanks for your time and patience to help me friend, that really was the case, and really interesting to know.

Comment: However, that is not the only problem in the posted code